# I need to fetch the datepicker value in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I need to choose a date from my datepicker and i need to submit that date to my database(mysql). Previously I have used textfield for the date and i got the the expected output. Now i need to use datePicker,How to use my datePicker to submit my selected date to the mysql database? Thanks in advance,any suggestions would be 
appreciable
I have created my calendar by using this four lines:

```
UtilDateModel model1 = new UtilDateModel();
     JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl(model1);
     JDatePickerImpl datePicker = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel,new DateLabelFormatter());
     datePicker.setBounds(130, 130, 180, 20);
```

Below is my query,that i have used date as a textfield:

```
theQuery("insert into Files5(FileName,LinesCount,UserId,Date,Time) values('"+JT_FileName.getText()+"','"+JT_LinesCount.getText()+"','"+JT_UserId1.getText()+"','"+JT_Date1.getText()+"','"+JT_Time1.getText()+"')");
```

Now how can i replace my JT_DATE1 with my datePicker

Comment: 1. Use `PreparedStatement` - it will allow you to pass object based data to the query, rather then `String`s; 2. I recommend using the `SqlDateModel` instead; 3. Use `datePicker.getModel().getValue()` return the currently selected date

Comment: okay let me try and thanks @MadProgrammer

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Actually i m new to the database and i m stuggling to convert the statement into the prepared statement and i dont have any idea.

Comment: [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: thanks once again i will refer the above site

Comment: Data Truncation:Incorrect date Value:for column 'Date' at row 1

Comment: i got this error message @MadProgrammer

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Using what query?

Comment: PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Files5 where Date=? ");

Comment: i don't have any problem with my gui @AndrewThompson

Comment: PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Files5");
                ResultSet Rs = pstm.executeQuery();
                while(Rs.next()){
                   Vector row = new Vector();
                   row.add(Rs.getString("FileName"));
                   row.add(Rs.getInt("LinesCount"));
                   row.add(Rs.getString("UserId"));
                   row.add(Rs.getString("Date"));
                   row.add(Rs.getString("Time"));

                   data.add(row);

Comment: my whole query part @MadProgrammer

Comment: *"i don't have..:* What about the **next** user using a different screen size, screen resolution.. (etc.). If this program is only for you (with all those other things locked in) it's not going to be a problem.

Comment: sorry @AndrewThompson

Comment: waiting for your comment@MadProgrammer